# Python 'stringvar' no se puede convertir a un tipo MySQL

Tags: mysql, python

Muy buenas, la verdad es la primera vez que posteo algo en un sitio web, pero iré directo al grano. Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto para el cual he empleado Visula Studio justo con Python y XAMMP(mysql), lo he estado haciendo bien hasta que me tope con este problema, al intentar agregar datos a mi tabla creada en mi base de datos, desde la interfaz que he creado en Visual Studio (con ayuda de la librería tkinter) me arroja el presente problema "Python 'stringvar' cannot be converted to a MySQL type", le he preguntado a mi profesor que me asesora y me ha dicho que hay una forma de "convertir" el tipo de dato por así decirlo, no estoy muy seguro si sea verdad o no, pero he estado buscando en diferentes foros, paginas web, etc. y no he podido encontrarlo, me gustaria saber que es lo que puedo hacer para que me deje de arrojar ese error y se puedan almacenar bien los datos en mi tabla creada en la base de datos de mysql.

**Cabe mencionar que para mis variables a guardar utilice la clase de variable tipo Tk.StringVar() ya que al poner solo StringVar() el programa me marcaba como errónea la sintaxis.

A continuación adjunto una imagen como muestra de la sintaxis de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación adjunto el código completo:

```
import mysql.connector
import tkMessageBox
import commands
import ttk
import Tkinter as Tk 
import ScrolledText as st
import Biomedico
import Tkconstants

class IniciodeSecion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana1=Tk.Tk()
        self.labelframe=ttk.LabelFrame(self.ventana1, text="Login:")        
        self.labelframe.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)        
        self.login()        
        self.ventana1.mainloop()

    def login(self):
        self.label15=ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text="Nombre de usuario:")
        self.label15.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.Nombredeusuario=Tk.StringVar()
        self.entry1=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, textvariable=self.Nombredeusuario)
        self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.label0=ttk.Label(self.labelframe, text="Ingrese clave:")        
        self.label0.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.passwd=Tk.StringVar()
        self.entry2=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe, show="*", textvariable=self.passwd)
        self.entry2.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.boton4=ttk.Button(self.labelframe, text="Ingresar", command=self.acceso)
        self.boton4.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

    def acceso(self):
        if self.Nombredeusuario.get()=="ejemplo" and self.passwd.get()=="1234":
            class Inicio:
                def __init__(self):
                    self.Biomedico=Biomedico.Biomedico()
                    self.ventana1=Tk.Tk()
                    self.ventana1.title("Programa X")
                    self.cuaderno1=ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)  
                    self.Agregar_Biomedico()      
                    self.Agregar_Equipo()
                    self.Modificar_Fecha()
                    self.Personal_Biomedico()
                    self.Mantenimiento()
                    self.Asignar_Equipo()
                    self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
                    self.ventana1.mainloop()

                def Agregar_Biomedico(self):
                    self.pagina1=ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
                    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text="Agregar Biomedico")
                    self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text="Registro de Personal")        
                    self.labelframe1.grid(column=10, row=10, padx=10, pady=10)

                    self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Nombre:")
                    self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.Nombre=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entrynombre=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.Nombre)
                    self.entrynombre.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Apellido:")
                    self.label2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.Apellido=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entryapellido=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.Apellido)
                    self.entryapellido.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label3=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Cedula:")        
                    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.cedula=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entrycedula=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.cedula)
                    self.entrycedula.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label4=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Cargo:")
                    self.label4.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.cargo=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entrycargo=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.cargo)
                    self.entrycargo.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label5=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Telefono:")
                    self.label5.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.telefono=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entrytelefono=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.telefono)
                    self.entrytelefono.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Registrar", command=self.registro)
                    self.boton1.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)

                def registro(self):
                    conexion1=mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", database="ejemplo")
                    cursor1=conexion1.cursor()
                    Nombres=self.Nombre 
                    Apellidos=self.Apellido
                    Cedula=self.cedula
                    Cargo=self.cargo
                    Telefono=self.telefono    
                    sql="""INSERT INTO biomedico (Nombres, Apellidos, Cedula, Cargo, Telefono) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
                    val=(Nombres, Apellidos, Cedula, Cargo, Telefono)
                    cursor1.execute(sql, val)
                    conexion1.commit()
                    cursor1.close()
                    conexion1.close()    

                def Agregar_Equipo(self):
                    self.pagina2=ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
                    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina2, text="Agregar Equipo")
                    self.labelframe2=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina2, text="Registro de Equipo")        
                    self.labelframe2.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

                    self.label6=ttk.Label(self.labelframe2, text="Nombre del Equipo:")
                    self.label6.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.Nombredelequipo=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entrynombredelequipo=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe2, textvariable=self.Nombredelequipo)
                    self.entrynombredelequipo.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label7=ttk.Label(self.labelframe2, text="Folio:")
                    self.label7.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.Folio=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entryfolio=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe2, textvariable=self.Folio)
                    self.entryfolio.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label8=ttk.Label(self.labelframe2, text="Area:")
                    self.label8.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.Area=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entryarea=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe2, textvariable=self.Area)
                    self.entryarea.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label9=ttk.Label(self.labelframe2, text="Fecha de Mantenimiento:")
                    self.label9.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.Fechademantenimiento=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entryfechademantenimiento=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe2, textvariable=self.Fechademantenimiento)
                    self.entryfechademantenimiento.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.boton2=ttk.Button(self.labelframe2, text="Registrar")
                    self.boton2.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)

                def Modificar_Fecha(self):
                    self.pagina3=ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
                    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina3, text="Modificar Fecha")
                    self.labelframe3=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina3, text="Modificacion de Fecha")        
                    self.labelframe3.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

                    self.label10=ttk.Label(self.labelframe3, text="Folio del Equipo:")
                    self.label10.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.Foliodeequipo=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entryfoliodeequipo=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe3, textvariable=self.Foliodeequipo)
                    self.entryfoliodeequipo.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label11=ttk.Label(self.labelframe3, text="Nueva Fecha de Mantenimiento:")
                    self.label11.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.NFDM=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entrynfdm=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe3, textvariable=self.NFDM)
                    self.entrynfdm.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.boton3=ttk.Button(self.labelframe3, text="Modificar")
                    self.boton3.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

                def Personal_Biomedico(self):
                    self.pagina4=ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
                    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina4, text="Personal Biomedico")
                    self.labelframe4=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina4, text="Modificacion de Personal")        
                    self.labelframe4.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

                    self.label14=ttk.Label(self.labelframe4, text="Ingrese Nombre:")        
                    self.label14.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.nombre=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entry4=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe4, textvariable=self.nombre)
                    self.entry4.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.boton7=ttk.Button(self.labelframe4, text="Buscar") #command=self.Buscarpersonal)
                    self.boton7.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

                #def Buscarpersonal(self):
                    #if self.nombre()=="Todos":
                        #conexion1=mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", database="proyecto")
                        #cursor1=conexion1.cursor()
                        #cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM Biomedico;")
                        #for fila in cursor1:
                           #print (fila)
                        #conexion1.close()

                def Mantenimiento(self):
                    self.pagina5=ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
                    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina5, text="Mantenimiento")
                    self.labelframe5=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina5, text="Fechas de Mantenimiento")        
                    self.labelframe5.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

                def Asignar_Equipo(self):
                    self.pagina6=ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
                    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina6, text="Asignar Equipo")
                    self.labelframe6=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina6, text="Asignacion de Equipos")        
                    self.labelframe6.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

                    self.label12=ttk.Label(self.labelframe6, text="Cedula del Biomedico:")
                    self.label12.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.Ceduladelbiomedico=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entryceduladelbiomedico=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe6, textvariable=self.Ceduladelbiomedico)
                    self.entryceduladelbiomedico.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.label13=ttk.Label(self.labelframe6, text="Folio del Equipo:")
                    self.label13.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
                    self.FDE=Tk.StringVar()
                    self.entryfde=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe6, textvariable=self.FDE)
                    self.entryfde.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

                    self.boton6=ttk.Button(self.labelframe6, text="Asignar")
                    self.boton6.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

            aplicacion=Inicio() 

        else:
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Advertencia", "Ingrese un Usuario y/o Clave Correcta")

aplicacion2=IniciodeSecion()
```

Comment: Bienvenido al SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Adicionalmente te invito a [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/247872/edit) la pregunta para que agregues el código de tu proyecto como texto (en lugar de la imagen) por diferentes beneficios que trae colocar el código como texto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bienvenida, no he agregado el código completo porque la verdad es algo extenso, pero si tienes razón en que serviría de mucho echarle un ojo para dar algún apoyo o consejo, editare la pregunta saludos.

Comment: Con toda seguridad, no hubiera hecho falta poner todo el código. Al date el error mysql, podías haber aislado las partes en las que se invocan las queries y quitar el resto para que moleste menos. Puede servirte de ayuda las normas sobre ["Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saber localizar el error es también parte de saber solucionarlo.

Comment: Hola tengo el mismo problema podrías indicarme como solucionaste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes al ejecutar la *query*:

```
...
Nombres=self.Nombre 
Apellidos=self.Apellido
Cedula=self.cedula
Cargo=self.cargo
Telefono=self.telefono    
sql="""INSERT INTO biomedico (Nombres, Apellidos, Cedula, Cargo, Telefono) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
val=(Nombres, Apellidos, Cedula, Cargo, Telefono)
cursor1.execute(sql, val)
...
```

Los datos que quieres insertar son de tipo `StringVar` que el conector de Mysql no sabe cómo convertir.

Lo más sencillo sería convertir los datos antes de ejecutar la query:

```
Nombres = self.Nombre.get()
Apellidos = self.Apellido.get()
Cedula = self.cedula.get()
Cargo = self.cargo.get()
Telefono = self.telefono.get()
val = (Nombres, Apellidos, Cedula, Cargo, Telefono)
```

Pero en aplicaciones más complejas podría ser un riesgo ir convirtiendo las variables `StringVar` y dejarte alguna. Un mecanismo más seguro sería enseñar al conector de mysql cómo se hace la conversión. Para ello podemos crear un *"convertidor"* a partir de `MySQLConverter`:

```
from mysql.connector import conversion

class MyConverter(conversion.MySQLConverter):
    def _stringvar_to_mysql(self, value):
        """Convert a StringVar to string"""
        return str(value.get())
```

Al conectar con la base de datos, se le pasa esta clase conversora:

```
conexion1 = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="ejemplo",
    converter_class=MyConverter
)
```

Comment: Vale, me ha servido de mucho, pero ahora me he topado con otro problema, lo que pasa es que al momento de que ingreso datos desde mi interfaz hasta la mi tabla (en mysql), estos mismos no se ven reflejados, más bien en mi tabla solo aparecen campos vacíos.

Comment: ¿Has probado sin interface gráfico?¿Has probado a hacer un `print` de los argumentos antes del `cursor.execute`?

Comment: Me he puesto analizar la sintaxis con ayuda de un doctor de mi universidad y hemos encontrado el error, de antemano te doy las gracias por haberme ayudado con el primer problema, saludos.